# Flash Drive Dead After ubuntu install

Tags: boot, partitioning, flash

I installed ubuntu recently on my 32gb flash drive. Before then it was working fine. I just wanted to use ubuntu in my place of work where the default is windows. After partitioning the drive during the installation process, the installation failed nearing completion. Now, my drive is neither recognized by windows or Ubuntu. I tried both create partitions in windows and gparted in ubuntu the flash drive just isn't there. I even tried it on different computers, it cannot be seen. The  `lsblk` command in ubuntu still does not show it. Any ideas

Answer (score 1):

Coincidence. An unfortunate coincidence.

I've used dozens of flash drives and installed Ubuntu hundreds of times over more than a decade. Ubuntu does NOT magically kill flash drives.

From your description, seems like you have taken the correct steps to troubleshoot the hardware, and have demonstrated that the hardware has become faulty. Flash drive components do wear out, regardless of what's on them or how they have been used. They do tend to wear out at the worst possible times.

- If it's a new flash drive, it may still be under warranty. Failure of a new flash drive is rare, but does occasionally happen. Try to return or exchange it.
- If it's an older flash drive, then briefly reflect on all the good service it has provided, then replace it.

Comment: +1; @CaveinMuthama, I think this is a good answer. Maybe [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) can add some details if you want to analyze the problem.